# Installed ibpy2 but cannot import

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ibpy

I installed Ibpy2 to connect to my interactive broker account.

https://github.com/blampe/IbPy

I installed IbPy2 successfully (by installing `pip install IbPy2` AND `python setup.py install`).

However, when I open Spyder in Anaconda and run `from IBWrapper import IBWrapper, contract`. It says:

> No module named 'IBWrapper'.

Please advise how I may fix it. Many, many thanks!

Comment: There is no IBWrapper class in IBPy.  That's someone else's program.  Search github for it if you really want that.  IB has it's own python API now that you should probably use  instead.  Get it from IB.

Answer (score 0):

IbPy is outdated, it's a 3rd party module that's no longer supported as there is an official Python module available.

If you wish to use a IbPy like interface to interact with the official API, use IbPythonic. It's almost identical to IbPy with minor adjustments, for example IbPy has 'm_' prefixes in functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to  https://github.com/anthonyng2/ib It is third party python file that you may directly code

`from IBWrapper import IBWrapper, contract`

You need to download the IBWrapper.py file and copy it into your python library path.